# Sort file line based on reg expression

Tags: regex, linux, sorting, sed

I have lines in my test file as

```
2018-05-28T17:13:08.024 {"operation":"INSERT","primaryKey":{"easy_id":1234},"subSystem":"ts\est","table":"tbl","timestamp":1527495188024}
```

I have to sort lines based on `timestamp` field. I using `sed` to extract `timestamp` and trying to place as 1st column using `sed  -e 's/((?<=\"timestamp\":)\d+.*?)/\1` .
Can anyone help to fix reg exp.

Right now getting Error : `sed: 1: "s/((?<=\"timestamp\":)\ ...": \1 not defined in the RE` . I think error is coming because of my regex.

Comment: `sed` does not support lookarounds like `(?<=...)`. Well, you have not written a POSIX BRE pattern, but a PCRE-like pattern, why use `sed` then? Use `perl`.

Comment: I am following https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45408/sort-input-file-by-the-results-of-a-regex

Comment: Then write a POSIX pattern if you want it to be compatible with `sed`. Do not use `\d`, use `[0-9]`. Remove `(?<=` and its closing `)`. Use `-E` option to use ERE syntax.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok ..  i will check more on sed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**`awk`**: This solution works in the general case where `timestamp` can appear anywhere :

```
awk 'BEGIN {FPAT="\"timestamp\": *[0-9]*"; PROCINFO["sorted_ in"]="@ind_num_asc" }
     { a[substr($1,13)]=$0 }
     END { for(i in a) print a[i] }' <file>
```

This states that your line contains a single field of the form `"timestamp": nnnnnnnn`. It also assumes that all arrays are numerically ascending sorted based on their key. The second part removes the `"timestamp":` part from the field `$1` which is the key now and stores it in an array. In the end, we print the array.

Comment: Not all file has json format. but all  line has `timestamp` present in line. Thanks

Comment: @rana_stack I have added an alternative approach.

Comment: `timestamp`  field is not at fixed position. Thanks

Comment: @rana_stack well ... then these two solutions are extremely useless to you ... no ;-)

Comment: Not getting correct result. some ssample test message : ``` 2018-05-27T17:01:08.665 {"operation":"INSERT","primaryKey":{"easy_id":111,"system_id":"t"},"subSystem":"t","table":"tbl4","timestamp":1527408068665}
{"operation":"INSERT","primaryKey":{"easy_id":222},"subSystem":"c","table":"tbl1","timestamp":1523925956394}
{"operation":"INSERT","primaryKey":{"easy_id":33},"subSystem":"g","table":"tb2","timestamp":1527318330242} ```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172905/discussion-between-rana-stack-and-kvantour).

Comment: Since the requirements are not clear and your solution is adapted to the initial query +1!

Answer (score 1):

You can do a quick implementation with `gawk` as well, without creating any intermediate columns etc.

**Command:**

```
awk -F'"timestamp":' '{a[substr($2,1,length($2)-1)]=$0}END{asorti(a,b);for(i in b){print a[b[i]]}}' input
```

**Explanations:**

- `-F'"timestamp":'` you define `"timestamp":` as field separator
- `{a[substr($2,1,length($2)-1)]=$0}` on each line of your file you save the timestamp value as an index and the whole line in an associative array
- `END{asorti(a,b);for(i in b){print a[b[i]]}}` at the end of the processing you sort the associative array on the index (the timestamp) and you print the content of the array based on the sorted indexes.

**input:**

```
$ more input
2018-05-28T17:15:08.026 {"operation":"DELETE","primaryKey":{"easy_id":1236},"subSystem":"ts\est2","table":"tbl1","timestamp":1527495188026}
2018-05-28T17:13:08.024 {"operation":"INSERT","primaryKey":{"easy_id":1234},"subSystem":"ts\est","table":"tbl","timestamp":1527495188024}
2018-05-28T17:14:08.025 {"operation":"UPDATE","primaryKey":{"easy_id":1235},"subSystem":"ts\est1","table":"tbl1","timestamp":1527495188025}
```

**output:**

```
awk -F'"timestamp":' '{a[substr($2,1,length($2)-1)]=$0}END{asorti(a,b);for(i in b){print a[b[i]]}}' input                      
2018-05-28T17:13:08.024 {"operation":"INSERT","primaryKey":{"easy_id":1234},"subSystem":"ts\est","table":"tbl","timestamp":1527495188024}
2018-05-28T17:14:08.025 {"operation":"UPDATE","primaryKey":{"easy_id":1235},"subSystem":"ts\est1","table":"tbl1","timestamp":1527495188025}
2018-05-28T17:15:08.026 {"operation":"DELETE","primaryKey":{"easy_id":1236},"subSystem":"ts\est2","table":"tbl1","timestamp":1527495188026}
```

Comment: I will check. Thanks

Comment: @Allan, this will fail if various timestamps have a different amount of digits as the sorting not numeric.

Comment: @kvantour: I do agree with you at 100%! However note that if the script is used from today the timestamp in seconds will have the same number of digits until we reach `10000000000000` therefore we still have approximately `10000000000000` - `1527495188024` =  `8,472,504,811,976` seconds before this happens! In hours: `23534735589`, `980613982.9` days , `2,686,614` years. So if this `awk` command lives long enough to fail in the sorting operation it would be a miracle! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use sort command:

```
sort -t: -k8 inputfile
```

Here `-t:` lets the colon `:` be the delimiter. The sort is done by the eight  field because the colon in `timestamp":` is the eight colon in the line.

Comment: Since the requirements are not clear and your solution is adapted to the initial query +1!